Выравнивание памяти
Есть вот такая структура:
Struct MyStruct
{
  double d;
  char c;
}

Почему компилятор в случае с 32-битной системой добавляет после char c padding размером 3 байта, а в случае с 64-битной системой 7 байт? Ведь из памяти насколько я знаю всё равно читается кэш-линия размером 64 байта и в том и другом случае, так почему тогда для 32-битной системы достаточно выравнивания по границе 4 байта?

из памяти насколько я знаю всё равно читается кэш-линия размером 64 байта. Во всех процессорах произведённых человечеством на данный момент? ;) В «32-битных Линуксах» у 8-байтного типа double требование по выравниванию равно 4. Что несколько неожиданно. Так обязывает System V ABI for i386. И такое выравнивание судя по всему пришло из тех далёких времён, когда более строгое 8-байтное выравнивание для double не давало преимуществ. См. Double stack alignment question using gcc compiler for x86 architecture

Это выравнивание не для этой структуры "MyStruct", а для той, что может расположиться в памяти после неё, например "MyStruct_2".

@PRODIGY или другой такой же структуры MyStruct например в случае массива

@wololo, а сделайте из своего комментария ответ (полезно про  System V ABI for i386)

Я вот не совсем понимаю, выравнивание необходимо чтобы поле структуры не пересекало границу двух кэш-линий? То есть необходимо сделать так, чтобы данные самого большого размера с которым умеет оперировать процессор не пересекали границу кэш-линии, а сделать это можно только если данные можно будет сгруппировать в блоки размером разрядности процессора?

выравнивание необходимо чтобы поле структуры не пересекало границу двух кэш-линий? И для этого тоже. Но даже если некоторый объект, например типа int, целиком лежит внутри кеш-линии, но при этом не выровнен подходящим образом, то доступ к нему может быть замедлен. Или попытка доступа к нему может вызвать аппаратное исключение. См. Выравнивание данных и Почему процессор "не любит" невыровненные данные? В общем, всё сильно зависит от аппаратных особенностей конкретного процессора/архитектуры.

Вот пример программы, в которой мы с помощью функции std::assume_aligned убеждаем компилятор, что указатель p указывает на якобы выровненные по 16-байтной границе данные, чтобы компилятор для повышения производительности программы мог смело использовать специфичные инструкции процессора, требующие 16-байтного выравнивания. Если p действительно указывает на подходящим образом выровненные данные, то программа успешно работает, если же нет, то программа аварийно завершается.

Честно говоря все равно не догнал :) Как int лежащий целиком внутри кэш-линии, но не выровненный  может вызывать замедление. Я сначала подумал, что может еще есть задержки при обращении к не выровненным данным в оперативной памяти, но кажется такое невозможно потому что из памяти считываются блоки размером 64 байта, а значит мы не передаем на шину адреса младшие 6 бит. Эти 6 бит учитываются только внтури кэш-линии при обращении к определенному байту.

Хотя как уже выше заметили такое поведение не во всех процессорах, поэтому скорее всего замедление доступа к данным из оперативной памяти тоже может быть.
